# Вывод рубрик и последних новостей WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день! Помогите сделать вывод рубрик и последней новости из каждой рубрики.

Что имею сейчас:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3&caller_get_posts=1'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="category-post-img" style="background:url(<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>) no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
                    <div class="category-tumb">
                        <div class="category-romb">
                            <div style="background:url(<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>) no-repeat; background-size:cover; transform: rotate(45deg);width: 200%;height: 200%; position:relative; left:-40px; top:-40px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="category-romb-img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-img-text">
                        <h1><?php the_category(' '); ?></h1>
                        <div class="category-img-text-sep">
                        </div>
                        <h2><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category-post">
                    <div class="category-text">
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <p>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <div class='category-text-sep'></div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

То есть сейчас выводятся первые 3 поста. Нужно, чтобы выводились последние посты по одному из каждой рубрики и через каждые 3 поста `<div class="row"></div>` повторялся с следующими 3мя постами внутри. Т.е. кол-во постов должно быть равно кол-ву категорий.